# Social Sharing not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am new in phonegap. I have configure and install Social Sharing plugin from [github Social-Sharing-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/). When i run cordova app by `cordova run wp8` then it show error message

`Plugins\cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing\SocialSharing.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The
 type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a usin
g directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\xampp\htdocs\myapps\platforms\wp8\AdvisoryMandi.csproj]`

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the plugin by this code in Terminal, cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing and reinstall by cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing. Try to rebuild the app it may work.